# Is there a downloadable data source for mapping out rivers with names for the whole world?

Tags: data, hydrology, hydrography

I'd like to be able to extract rivers with their names and the flow size (not direction) for the whole world. The scale I'll be drawing it at is about 2 centimeters per 10 real world km - nothing too precise! At this point I've looked at the hydrosheds dataset available for download and it seems great except for missing the river names...do you guys know of any other that is available for download?

I've also looked at the HYDRO1K (unable to download) and the Global Runoff World Rivers...I can't get a copy (asked already). Or - do you know how I could automate the naming of rivers after I have drawn them from hydrosheds? In other words - some online DB or API that I can use lat-long to ask for river name at this or that lat-long coordinate? I use Java and am expecting to have to code this out by using lat-long pairs...

Thanks!

Comment: OpenStreetMap has most rivers worldwide (and names). Not quite sure what flow size means, but it is differentiated between river, stream, etc. It might be a little bit work to extract the features. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:waterway

Answer (score 1):

This may be of use [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-rivers-lake-centerlines/)